# Merge commit with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I was wondering whether it is possible to merge commit with IntelliJ IDEA?

Right now when I do `merge` and then `push`, it appears as a single in GitHub page.

[image]

I would like to do `merge commit` so that it stays consistent with my lectures. My lecturer teaches us to use `merge commit` when using Eclipse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, if you don't use the Git branches widget in the status bar on the lower right. There it does a fast-forward merge if possible.

Instead use a shortcut or the menu to open the merge dialog. In the menu it is at `VCS -> Git -> Merge Changes...`.

There select the branch(es) you want to merge and set the checkmark for `No fast forward` which is the setting according to `--no-ff` on the commandline and will cause a merge commit to be created even if a fast-forward merge would be possible.